# Invalid MailChimp List ID

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, mailchimp

I am using Codeigniter library to integrate mailchimp and its return

```
Invalid MailChimp List ID
```

I have create several list and try with the new id its not working..

I have tried another account its work with it.

```
            $this->load->library('mcapi');   
        echo $listID = '12a5b20dda'; // obtained by calling lists();
        $merge_vars = array(
         'COUPON' => $token
        );

         $retval = $this->mcapi->listSubscribe($listID, $emailAddress,$merge_vars);  

        if ($this->mcapi->errorCode): 
           $error="Unable to subscribe email using listSubscribe()!";  
            echo "\n\tCode=".$this->mcapi->errorCode;  
            echo "\n\tMsg=".$this->mcapi->errorMessage."\n";  
        else:
            return TRUE;
        endif;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you have problem with your api key, replace your api key with that one which is working.